# jquery - traverse up tree and find elements with specified class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I thought that the `closest()` function would do this for me, but seemingly not. I have the following markup and I want to add a `class` to all parent anchors with the class trigger:

```
    <ul>
    <li class="selected">
      <a class="trigger" href=""></a> 
      <a href=""></a>
      <ul>
        <li class="selected">
          <a class="trigger" href=""></a> 
          <a href="" id = "my_target"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I want to select my target - in this example, the deepest anchor, then add a `class` to each `a.trigger` in its ascendants. What would be the best way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using a combination of [`jQuery.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) (to get the containing `<li>` tags) and then [`jQuery.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to get the `<a>` tags with a class of *trigger*:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#my_target').click( function(e) {
        $(this).parents('li.selected').children('a.trigger').addClass('myclass');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/antelopelovefan/AND7R/5/)

**EDIT:**

Note `$().parents()` traverses all the way up the tree, but `$().children()` only traverses down one level. To gather all descendents of an element use `$().find()`.

Comment: I'll add a jsfiddle example as soon as they're back online :)

Comment: Didn't know about jsbin, thanks!  Not as clean as jsfiddle but it'll do in a pinch.

Comment: @MarkBiek - `parents()` seems to traverse all the way up the DOM tree and grab all my items, but when I get to that top item and try to traverse down and gather all links down the tree `.children('a')` it doesn't seem to find any. Does children not travel down the tree?

Comment: Forget that... I found the answer in the fine print on the jQuery site.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use

```
$('#my_target').parents('a.trigger');
```

Using the [.parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) method (which traverses all the way up the DOM tree, rather than [.parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/), which only traverses one level up.

Answer (score 0):

`parents` Is used for traversing up.

I believe this should work:

```
$('#my_target').parents('.trigger').addClass('myclass');
```

However for siblings you'll need to use `siblings` instead of `parents`
For example the `anchor` tag that is with the `#my_target` anchor is considered a sibling.